# How to pass html element into rowDragText callback

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible. I want to present the "floating" DOM element created when dragging a row as something more than just text. Seems like when I try to use html code as the returned value it is rendered as text rather than html:

```
rowDragText: function(params) {
   return `<div [innerHTML]=${params.rowNode.data.RULE_NAME}></div>`;
}
```

This is what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is `public static GHOST_TEMPLATE` defined in `dragAndDropService.ts`.
You can try modifiying that template and perhaps also inspect the `createGhost` function nearby.

`rowDragText` probably not used with this method...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Not sure I want to go that way but I really appreciate the suggestion!